# Laravel Passport - Access token without user

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0

I have a Mobile application which uses `oauth` for authenticating users into the the app and getting/posting data to the API.

Currently I am using `password` grant types, which relies on a user entering their username & password. This is fine for carrying out tasks that the user needs to be authenticated for, however, the application itself needs to carry out duties that are not related to the application itself but only this application can be granted access.

What I therefore wondering - Is it possible to create a `client` which does not require a username/password in order to be given an access token so that the tasks (reading / writing) data can be done once authenticated? The access token can be granted for a long period of time and we are also implementing a way to refresh the token so the application can communicate with certain aspects of the API.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I am looking into using the personal access tokens for this but having issues.

Comment: @Yani - sadly not I believe you can use JWT tokens?

Comment: I am currently looking into using Passport/OAuth 'personal access clients' which seems as it is working even when no user is attached to the token. Kind of a hack but might work.

Comment: Have you looked into this? - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#personal-access-tokens

Comment: @Yani ooo that sounds good! I always thought it was for when you wanted your user to create their own clients etc... that's why the redirect works, I'll check this out

Comment: After bashing my head against the computer all day I ended up implementing a custom middleware that simply receives an API key at the header and verifies against a client_api_keys database table. Took about 10 minutes to implement after 8 hours of fighting with OAuth and Laravel custom authentication guards.

Comment: @Yani Woo! If you get time, please could you write it as an answer please? I'd love to see your implementation and also it can answer this question for future uses